# WPF Listview display multiple rows with a template

Tags: .net, wpf-controls

In WPF I have a ListView that is bound to a table in a Dataset. If I use (Commented out in full code view:

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
  <GridViewColumn>
```

I get the rows displayed and I can see multiple rows and scroll through the rest.

If I try

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           'Put a bunch of controls here bound to various columns in my data table
```

I can only see one row/record at one time. Am I missing a setting on one of the controls or is the ListView.ItemTemplate only going to show one record at a time.

I'm looking for something in WPF that is more like a Repeater control where I can have different controls for each record in a particular layout.

Full xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="GridTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="GridTest" Height="661" Width="750">

        <ListView Margin="4,1,8,1" 
                  Name="ListView_Transactions"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <!--<ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Transactions">
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TransactionHeaderID}" />


            </GridView>

            </ListView.View>-->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid MaxHeight="600">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Amount}" Height="25" Name="Label_Amount" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Margin="50,201,526,0" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding ActivityCategory}" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Label_ActivityCategory" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Margin="208,201,0,0" />
                            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="TextBox_Customer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" Margin="440,201,0,0" />
                            <Button Content="Breakout" Height="20" Name="Button_Breakout" Width="90" BorderThickness="0" ClickMode="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,244,0,223">

                            </Button>
                            <Label Content="{Binding ShortDescription}" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Label_ShortDescription" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Margin="50,270,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Height="65" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="TextBlock_LogDescription" Text="{Binding LongDescription}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Margin="50,303,0,0" />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

</Window>
```

[image: View of result, text does render normally, but smudged for security purposes]

**Cleaned Up My Mess:**

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl Name="ItemsC" ItemsSource="{Binding}">         
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                         <DockPanel >
                             <Label Content="{Binding Amount}" Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="Label_Amount" Width="100" />
                                <Label Content="{Binding ActivityCategory}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="24" Name="Label_ActivityCategory" Width="100"  />
                                <TextBox Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  Name="TextBox_Customer" Width="123"  />
                            </DockPanel>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Button Content="Breakout"  Height="25" Name="Button_Breakout" Width="90" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <Label Content="{Binding ShortDescription}" Name="Label_ShortDescription" Width="550" />
                                <TextBlock Height="200" Name="TextBlock_LogDescription" Text="{Binding LongDescription}" Width="550"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe you do not need a `ListView`. `ItemsControl` in my opinion is direct equivalent for `Repeater`
2. Your `ItemTemplate` is messed up completely - I believe it causes your problems. Instead of putting everything into one `Grid` you should use several (probably nested) `DockPanels`/`StackPanels`. Remove all your fantastic margins - it should help. VS designer does his job badly creating a XAML, that's why I prefer editing XAML on my own.

Comment: Went with the itemcontrol and Dock/Stack panels. Much easier to work with now. I made an edit of the new code.